# Obtaining and Comparing Integers in a String

Tags: excel, vba, string-conversion

I'm trying to take a string input with numbers, ex. (1, 5, 7, 10, 16, 53, 2) and analyze it to see if any one value is >=some integer value.

I know that there's a sort of parseInt function but I don't think this would work for the format and content of the string, as it contains multiple numbers separated by commas.
I know that there's also a function (InStr) to find a certain value in a string, but this doesn't fit my needs as it would require writing cases from 1 to 1000+.

Would transforming the string into an integer array work? Is it a complicated process for VBA?

pseudo code

```
Dim element As Range
Dim OrgListcolE As Range

For each element in OrgListcolE
    If there exists a value in the element.Value >=16 Then
        ...
    ElseIf there exists a value in element.Value >=51
        ...
    ElseIf there exists a value in element.Value >=251
        ...
    ElseIf there exists a value in element.Value >=1001
        ...
    End If
```

Comment: Use `Split` to split the string into an array, then convert array elements to `Long`.

Comment: Your post says numbers are in a string. The code is indicating the numbers are in a range `OrgListcolE`. Which is it?

Comment: The numbers are in a string format, but they are contained within a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop and check:

```
Sub topcheck()
    Dim s As String, limt As Long
    s = "1, 5, 7, 10, 16, 53, 2"
    arr = Split(s, ", ")
    limt = 50
    For Each a In arr
        If CLng(a) > limt Then
            MsgBox "a value in the string exceeds " & limt
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next a
    MsgBox "no value in the array exceeds " & limt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try this out.

Comment: Straight forward solution :+) - fyi maybe you are interested in alternative `FilterXML` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Option with `Evaluate()`:

```vb
Sub test1()
    numbers = "1, 5, 7, 10, 16, 53, 2"
    max_num = Evaluate("Max(" & numbers & ")")
    Debug.Print IIf(max_num > 20, "", "no ") & "any number exceed limit"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try this out.

Comment: You are checking if the highest input number (e.g. 53) exceeds a given limit. - Doesn't OP want the opposite asking 
*"to take a string input with numbers, ex. (1, 5, 7, 10, 16, 53, 2) and 
analyze it to see if any one value is >=some integer value"*?

Answer (score 0):

**`FilterXML()` approach**

The `FilterXML()` function, available since vers. 2013+, allows to return filtered numbers from a *(string)* list which has been transformed to well-formed xml content.

*XML content* and individual *limits* are passed as arguments to help function `chk` which assigns all findings to a "flat" 1-dim array as function result. `FilterXML()` applies a so called *XPath* expression on the xml content based on the given limits, thus forming a string via `"//s[.>=" & limit & "]"`.

**Example call**

```
Sub TestNumList()
'1) definitions
    Dim myString As String
    myString = "1,5,7,10,16,53,2"   ' comma separated list (here without spaces!)

    Dim xml As String               ' build xml content string
    xml = "<t><s>" & Replace(myString, ",", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>"

    Dim limits()                    ' define limits
    limits = Array(16, 51, 251, 1001)

'2) check results
    Dim i As Long, elems As Variant
    For i = LBound(limits) To UBound(limits)
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         elems = chk(xml, limits(i))              ' << help function chk
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Debug.Print "Limit " & limits(i) & ":", UBound(elems) & " elem(s) found.", Join(elems, ",")
    Next

End Sub
```

***Display in VB Editor's immediate window:***

```
    Limit 16:     2 elem(s) found.            16,53
    Limit 51:     1 elem(s) found.            53
    Limit 251:    0 elem(s) found.            
    Limit 1001:   0 elem(s) found.
```

**Help function `chk()`**

```
Function chk(xml As String, ByVal limit As Long)
'Purpose: assign listed numbers >= individual limit to 1-dim array
'Author:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
'Date:    2021-07-15
'a) filter elements greater or equal limit
    Dim tmp
    tmp = Application.FilterXML(xml, "//s[.>=" & limit & "]")
'b) return elements as 1-based "flat" 1-dim array
    If TypeName(tmp) = "Variant()" Then  ' found several elements
        chk = Application.Transpose(tmp) ' (change 1-based 2-dim to 1-dim array)
    ElseIf IsError(tmp) Then             ' found no elements at all
        chk = Array(Empty)               ' (empty)
    Else                                 ' found single element only
        ReDim tmp2(1 To 1)               ' provide for one element
        tmp2(1) = tmp                    ' (numeric value)
        chk = tmp2
    End If
End Function
```

**Recommended link to @JvdV 's nearly encyclopaedic post treating `FilterXML()`**

- [Extract substrings from string using `FilterXML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml/61837697#61837697)